# Ignore whitespace with PEG.js

Tags: javascript, parsing, lexical-analysis, peg

I want to ignore *whitespaces* and *new lines* with my grammar so they are missing in the [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online) output. Also, a literal within brackets should be returned in a new array.

**Grammar**

```js
start
  = 'a'? sep+ ('cat'/'dog') sep* '(' sep* stmt_list sep* ')'

stmt_list
  = exp: [a-zA-Z]+ { return new Array(exp.join('')) }

sep
  = [' '\t\r\n]
```

**Test case**

```
a dog( Harry )
```

**Output**

```js
[
   "a",
   [
      " "
   ],
   "dog",
   [],
   "(",
   [
      " "
   ],
   [
       "Harry"
   ],
   [
      " "
   ],
   ")"
]
```

**Output I want**

```js
[
   "a",
   "dog",
   [
      "Harry"
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to break up the grammar more, using more "non-terminals" (not sure if that's what you call them in a PEG):

```
start
  = article? animal stmt_list

article
  = article:'a' __ { return article; }

animal
  = animal:('cat'/'dog') _ { return animal; }

stmt_list
  = '(' _ exp:[a-zA-Z]+ _ ')' { return [ exp.join('') ]; }

// optional whitespace
_  = [ \t\r\n]*

// mandatory whitespace
__ = [ \t\r\n]+
```

Thanks for asking this question!

**Edit:**
To increase readability, have two productions: `_` and `__`

Comment: Thanks! There is just one thing: Try `dog( Harry )`. The article should be optional. Bringing the `?` from `'a'` (in article) to `article` (in start) will still return an empty string... Is this PEG.js related?

Comment: I think maybe making the "start" rule have "article?" would help.  Then, the "article" rule itself could be just `'a' sep*`

Comment: Then it would also allow `adog( Harry )`. Anyway, maybe I am using the wrong tool... I am havin a xdot [grammar](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) (xdot is based on dot) that I want to parse and draw to a canvas. Do you know of any other time-saving approach evaluating the grammar of the file (except of writing my own parser or using thigs like [canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) (not enough functionality))?

Comment: With the original (as in my answer), " dog( Harry )" is parsed correctly. The "article" is returned in the result as an empty string, but it does parse.

Comment: As to how to parse a `dot` file, the grammar is complicated enough that I think you need a "real" parser. It doesn't have to be PEG of course; you could write your own recursive descent parser in JavaScript or perhaps use something like [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/docs/). I don't have experience with PEG parsing but I think it's fascinating. :-)

Comment: not `[' '\t\r\n]` but `[ \t\r\n]`. `[' '\t\r\n]` will catch `'`.

Comment: There are some other ideas in this [published article on PEG](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~baford/packrat/popl04/peg-popl04.pdf#page=2) (See Figure 1)