# Parser doesn't stop parsing arbitrary newlines and whitespaces

Tags: parsing, lisp, peg, pegjs

So, I'm trying to write a very basic Lisp parser in pegjs and I got it to spit out the same code as long as the Lisp code was syntactically valid and fit on one line.

I wish to extend the parser to be able to accept any newline character inserted anywhere along with extra whitespace in the code.

So here's the code that **works** as long as everything is on one line:

```
Start
  = List

Character
  = [^\n" ""("")"]

LeftParenthesis
  = "("

RightParenthesis
  = ")"

WhiteSpace
  = " "

NewLine
  = "\n"

Token
  = token:Character+{return token.join("");}

Tuple
  = left:Token WhiteSpace+ right:List?{
        return left.concat([" "]).concat(right);
    }
  / Token

List
  = left:LeftParenthesis tuple:Tuple right:RightParenthesis{
        return left.concat(tuple).concat(right);
    }
  / Tuple
```

Then, in my attempt to allow for newlines and whitespaces, I tried changing the rule for "Tuple" to

```
Tuple
  = left:Token WhiteSpace+ (NewLine* WhiteSpace*)* right:List?{
        return left.concat([" "]).concat(right);
    }
  / Token
```

But this change causes pegjs to go into an infinite loop, although the addition to the rule is seemingly non-recursive.

**Note:** In case it's unclear what I'm trying to do, I'm writing a grammar such that pegjs spits out a parser that parses

```
(f x 
  (g y 
    (h z t)))
```

and spits out either the same code as a string or just

```
"(f x (g y (h z t)))"
```

Either works for me.

What my current working grammar does is take

```
(f x (g y (h z t)))
```

and output

```
"(f x (g y (h z t)))"
```

While it is trivial to allow for just one newline character after every "Token" or "Tuple", I wish to accept the following as legal code:

```
(f x

   (g     y (

       h z t) ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this question is very similar to [Ignore whitespace with PEG.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257184/ignore-whitespace-with-peg-js)

It's all about ignoring whitespaces and newlines. I actually don't know why the above code fails, but after playing around, I managed to get pegjs to do what I want

```
Start
  = List

Character
  = [^ \t\r\n"("")"]

LeftParenthesis
  = "("

RightParenthesis
  = ")"

Separator
  = [ \t\r\n]

Token
  = List
  / token:Character+{return token.join("");}

Tuple
  = first:Token second:Separator+ rest:Tuple*{
        return rest.length > 0 ? first.concat([" "]).concat(rest) : first;
    }
  / Token

List
  = left:LeftParenthesis Separator* token:Tuple Separator* right:RightParenthesis{
        return [left].concat(token).concat([right]).join("");
     }
```

So, when you give the following string to parse:

```
(f x

   (g     y (

       h z t) ) )
```

The parser outputs

```
"(f x (g y (h z t)))"
```

which is exactly what I wanted